# Calling require 'rubygems' in irb and rails console results => false.

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to use 'awesome_print' gem in irb and rails console but when I call $ require 'rubygems' it results false. I tried reloading but didn't work.

Comment: what version of ruby?

Comment: In that case my friend, you don't have to explicitly load rubygems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason it returns false is that RubyGems is already loaded.

To use awesome print in plain irb, you'll just need to include the gem manually, like this:

`require 'awesome_print'`

Or in Rails, you can either chuck it in your Gemfile, or also use `require 'awesome_print'`